# how to get to the post id of shared story with graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I get shared story feed with graph api.
In The result I have fields like :
type": "photo", 
"status_type": "shared_story", 
"object_id": "647332045296931"

the object_id is the photo object.
I need the post_id of that photo.

How can I get the post id with graph api from that point ?

Thanks

Comment: you will get it using the `post` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp
I got the post with the "status_type" = "shared_story".
I need the post id of the "objectid" in that post. can you please give more info ?

Comment: sorry, but the `object_id` is just a reference (kind of `foreign_key`), how can you get that value without getting the initial `id` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using fql get page_story_id(Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo):

[image]

Retrieve the page_story_id details:
[image]

Access the exact page at www base facebook using this page_story_id(replace underscore with "**/posts/**"):
[image]

The post_id can get via https://graph.facebook.com/420619404634864/feed too:
[image]

Or fql:

[image]

Updates:

For video, it is easier compare with photo type to find post_id from object_id.
As you can see on the screenshot, concate page id "155483697799865" and object id "4320084459885" with underscore is equal to post_id "155483697799865_4320084459885":
[image]

Let's visit the story page using these post_id(Again, replace underscore with "**/posts/**"):
[image]

To be clarify, what i answer is get original post_id for this object id, not post_id of share status.

For example, i share a video from coca-cola fan page, the object id 12345 get from "me/feed" is same with object id 12345 get from "coca-cola/feed", which point to the same video. However, the post_id is different. My answer is help you to find out original story post_id  (coca-cola upload a video), not the shared post_id(xxx Shared coca-cola's video)

Cheers

Comment: if the shared objectid is video, what is the fql I need to use ?
I checked video table, but did not see page_story_id .

Comment: Just curious, actually you're able to get post_id using graph.facebook.com/420619404634864/feed, the field is called "id".

Comment: mmmm with the photo I understand.
With the video I did not undertstand how from the objectid that exist in the **shared_story feed**, you can get the **original feed's post_id**.
Can you explain more about that ? thanks in advance !

Comment: thanks for reply.
we are talking about the same thing. I have the object_id and the shared feed and I want the post id of the original feed.

what I dont undertand is the fql about the video with limit 50.
if the shared feed is **very old**, getting only 50 post or 500 its not enough. mmmm any ideas ?

Comment: I need to know one thing before answer your question. I don't understand your app design, what API query you're using to fetch object_id and the shared feed which you're not able to get post_id on the same time?(Even though i already answered the question how to get post_id based on object_id)

Comment: new day. new mind.
after checking again your answer about the video type, i understand.
the fql with the limit 50 confused me and I thought it's part of the solution.


so incase of the shared video :
1. fql - get the owner of the object_id
2. query  owener_object_id

:)
Thanks !!!

Comment: more info for others who need the original post id :
incase sharing feeds of "status" type.
the original post id is in the "link" field.

Comment: update. I can get the pageId part from the story tags.(for some f**** reason the graph api explorer did not return this value)

Comment: How could we accomplish this using Android?

Comment: @Astrount Forget about it, FQL has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I hope you can help me with this, in php you use the syntax UID_PostUID, how to convert it to be used in Android? I hope you understand what I mean, in Android I need to use a graph path in UID_PostUID but I don't know how it looks like in Android