# Facebook Graph API (/posts/) always returns small image for shared content

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing a simple integration of a Facebook page's news feed into a site using the Facebook Graph API, specifically the [/{page-id}/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed) call which is essentially the same as the feed call except it only returns the posts that were published by the particular page.

My issue is that for shared posts the API is returning a small version of the image such as [this](https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAD0uuYN22CRyu1&w=130&h=130&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQIAniyiukkNF27d_pWsR3yLgC2iGV1-tM9eyUK4seAWsTWQzoYFUC_xmTcm0LylnDKouu6Smj4sNgi6bVdXYbhzygWA83tEBUMicNjX1CvPRUt1E_9hwjjyU1tDjMIVPvIJhSut4bKzB8ejaW9AAHao&cfs=1). I've seen work arounds where people have used the object_id to get larger versions of the image, my issue is that because this is a shared story no object_id exists.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I'm talking about when a page on Facebook shares a URL, not when a page shares another page's post. The issue I'm having is that the scraped image from the URL is always too small.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17279706/188331

Comment: I appreciate the help, but FQL is now deprecated.

Comment: Yes, scroll down in that question, there is a non-FQL solution.

Comment: I see what you're talking about, but it's not actually what I want. They're talking about when someone shares a page's post, getting the original post ID. My issue is that in my feed what is being shared is a URL, then Facebook is scraping to get the image, that particular image is always too small.